# Make distinct applications communicate

Tags: macos, architecture, ipc, message-passing

On OSX, I have a Rails web application(let's call it X) and a Natural Language Processing component written in Scala(let's call it Y).

I want the following workflow:

1. The user submits a document online to X.
2. X passes the document to Y.
3. Y does some processing and passes another document back to X.
4. X displays the document to the user.

X and Y are complete. However, right now their communication is very bad: they are both placing documents in a given folder(which I have hardcoded in both).

What is a good and clean way of making them communicate?

Comment: what about a socket? named pipe? database?

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods you could use including a named pipe, socket, shared memory or a database[0].

Do you have more specific requirements that would assist in the decision? What's bad about using the filesystem?

http://www.slideshare.net/Hem_Dutt/ipc-on-mac-osx